# Where do the UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx logs get saved in Azure PaaS?

Tags: azure, paas, update-packages

Sitecore 9.0.2.

In my experience, the logs should be saved into the temp folder. Our environment is configured like so:

```
<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="d:\local\temp"/>
```

I've looked there and also in the `App_Data/logs` and `temp` folders below the website root, but the `__upgrade` folder is not present in any of these locations.

I know the installationLog.txt file is going somewhere... But WHERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That temp folder location is incorrect. That location (`d:\local\temp`) is temporary and is [not shared between the application and the Kudu tools](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files).

Relevant snippet from the above documentation:

> Another important note is that the Main site and the scm site do not share temp files. So if you write some files there from your site, you will not see them from Kudu Console (and vice versa). You can make them use the same temp space if you disable separation (via [WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#use-the-same-process-for-the-user-site-and-the-scm-site)). But note that this is a legacy flag, and its use is not recommended/supported.

To fix it, update the temp location to be below the web root:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <sc.variable name="tempFolder">
          <patch:attribute name="value">/temp</patch:attribute>
      </sc.variable>   
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Running another package installation thereafter will add the `__upgrade` folder to the website's `temp` folder which you can browse with the App Service Editor (or Kudu):

[image: photo of the app service editor with the upgrade logs viewed]

Answer (score 3):

There are likely additional places and methods for retrieving this data, but the following is typically what I resort to:

*Note: I have not tested SPECIFICALLY for UpdateInstallationWizard logs*

1. In Azure Portal, select the App Service resource that you used to run the installation.
2. Scroll down the blade and find `App Service logs` in the `Monitoring` section
3. Turn `Application Logging (Filesystem)` **On**
4. Change `Level` to **Verbose**
5. Save

[image: App Service Logs]

1. Select `Log stream` from `Monitoring` section
2. Select `Application logs`

[image: Log stream]

At this point, you will need to rerun the installation to capture new logs. Via `Log stream` you can view the current output of logs. If you wish to view historical logs (if you've previously configured this)- then you'll need to use Kudu.

### Kudu

1. From the App Service blade you used previously, select `Advanced Tools` from the `Development Tools` section.

[image: Kudu access]

2. Then press `Go ->` to open Kudu in a separate window
3. From the new window select `Debug console` > `PowerShell`

[image: Kudu PowerShell]

4. Next, drill down into `Log Files/Application` to view historically captured log files

By selecting `Verbose` previously, the log files will contain all messages. At this point, it's a matter of searching the log file for messages related to your installation.

[image: Application logs]

### temp\__upgrade Location

From Kudu, you can also drill down into that particular folder:

**site\wwwroot\temp**

Though I cannot confirm that the expected files will appear there as the instance I'm referencing does not have them (though it has many other expected temp files).

Comment: The first approach works well for watching logs, but unfortunately the update installation wizard logs don't show up there. Also unfortunately, Kudu's consoles do not show all the files because they open in a sandboxed version. _sad trombone_